# Modifying instructions using ida APIs

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

I want to change the Op value of an instruction using idautils and or idaapi.
For example, I have downloaded in memory a binary file, and I want to change the JMP address of a JMP statement (I know where the jump is and I can get the statement).
I tried to do something like this:

```
i = ida.idautils.DecodeInstruction(addr)
op = i.Op1
op.addr = new_addr
i.Op1.assign(op)
print i.Op1.addr
```

But the address is not changed.
Instead if I do:

```
i = ida.idautils.DecodeInstruction(addr)
op = idaapi.op_t()
op.addr = new_addr
i.Op1.assign(op)
print i.Op1.addr
```

It works, but when I look at the bytes (using [idaapi.get_bytes(addr+i) for i in range(0, i.size)] ), they are not changed.
I'd want to change that address, and see this change also when I read the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`PatchByte`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idc-module.html#PatchByte) (or [`idaapi.patch_byte`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi-module.html#patch_byte)).  Then you should see the correct value with `idaapi.get_byte`.  There are equivalent patch functions for words, dwords, and even variable-length buffers.

(Note that this requires you to know the exact byte encoding of the instruction you want to change)